What do I do on my summer vacation with an interest in mathematics?
I am a second year college student majoring in mathematics. The summer vacation is coming up and lasts for three months. I am thinking of studying something during this vacation that is specific to mathematics. I do not know what to study. Among the topics that I know in mathematics are calculus, real analysis, complex analysis, numerical analysis, and ordinary differential equations. What do I study?  Should I study another subject in mathematics, such as statistics, probability, etc.? Or do I develop my skills in integration, special functions, and infinite series?

It's too late for this summer, but for next summer, you should look for opportunities to get away from your university and learn more about future career options.  You can do this through internships in industry or by participating in a summer school or research program such as an REU in the US.

My advice would be to explore. You need to know what other fields are out there rather than try to master some particular field (although, depending on mindset, that can be an enjoyable vacation too!) There are obvious important and useful fields like probability and statistics, but there are also things like combinatorics, game theory, differential geometry, partial differential equations, dynamical systems, abstract algebra, etc. that should be pretty accessible at your level. So one approach is to get a bundle of introductory books and skim through them, not with the aim of necessarily going deep into them but to just know what they deal with. Some might strike your fancy and you will want to dive in, but it is not a bad idea to just see what is going on elsewhere and have at least an idea of what the bigger landscape is like.
(I like to browse math libraries, trying out different shelves to see what is going on. Similarly journals like The American Mathematical Monthly and SIAM Review are great to browse).
Behind all of this is the exploration-exploitation dilemma. You want to spend your time well, gaining useful knowledge. At first, you do not know what is the most useful and what you are best at, so it makes sense to explore widely. Over time you will notice where there is value for you, and you can focus on it.

You may take advantage of this vacations to not only study, but also to start getting an idea about what kind of specialisation you would like to pursue. This should help you during your choice.
Anyway, I think that, whatever path you will take, statistics an probability will pay off. It is always important to master the tools this field has to offer.
